# Wildcard file extensions xcopy

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I have some files that need to be copied to a directory on a schedule. All the files have the same name but the extension increments (I have no control over this, it drives me mad)

I've tried running `xcopy /C /D /Y /I "C:\Temp\Source" "C:\Temp\Destination"`

But I get a message it can't find the file.

Right now I've got a bit of a bodge in place that uses an excluded file extension list and copies anything that isn't in the list but I feel like it might be able to be done better.

Answer (score 3):

In your command line:

```
 xcopy /C /D /Y /I "C:\Temp\Source" "C:\Temp\Destination"
```

as far as I can see, you haven't told xcopy what to copy.  If you're trying to copy everything in C:\Temp\*.* then try:

```
 xcopy C:\Temp\*.* C:\Temp\Destination\ /C /D /Y /I
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `robocopy` instead of XCOPY. It supports the same options and allows to select file patterns:

```
robocopy source dest file(s) [options]
```

For file pattern you could use `?` for any single character, `*` for zero to multiple chars and so on. It would help if you gave an example of how the extensions are looking like.