# Copy files from one folder to another using a pattern based on input file in Windows

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, xcopy

I need some help using `for` and `xcopy` to move files from one folder to another based on an input text file. What I need help with is matching files based on a pattern.

My input file looks like this:

```
12345  
abcd
```

My source file directory looks like this:

```
12345_hr.jpg  
12345_hr1.jpg  
abcd_hr.jpg  
abcd_hr1.jpg
```

Lots of other files exist in this directory I want to ignore...

So I want to copy any file that matches the input file before the underscore (`_`); the end result would be all the files above being moved into a destination folder.

This is what I have used in the past when I want to do exact matches:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type FileList.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy ".\SourceFolder\%%a" ".\DestinationFolder"
```

I just don't know how to make that work with a pattern match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcard file extensions xcopy](https://superuser.com/questions/902452/wildcard-file-extensions-xcopy)

Comment: can you clarify a little more on what your desired outcome should be? is the input file essentially a list of folders, then if a file name (prior to the underscore) matches any one of those folder names, that file gets moved to that folder?

Comment: The outcome is to move filenames prior to the underscore that match what's in the input file. I'm trying to pull out approx 15k files out of 100k+ that match the input file names.

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out now. Here's what I was looking for:
`for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type list.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy "G:\Original\%%a"*.jpg "G:\Original\1"`

Comment: 1. No need to `type` the list file, just read it by `for /F` immediately. 2. The quotation of the source should be `"G:\Original\%%a_*.jpg"`, and there was the underscore missing...